# Value was either too large or too small for an Int32 in UWP Weather App

Tags: c#, uwp

So, I've been doing simple weather app, where I'm showing to user current weather by getting coordinates from the device. However I ran into a problem

```
 public async static Task<RootObject> GetWeather(double lat, double lon)
    {
        string AppID = "e72818716be6eb65476f5f25d4d32d82";
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var url = String.Format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={0}&lon={1}&units=metric&APPID=" + AppID, lat, lon);
        var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        var data = (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        return data;
    }
```

At "var data = ..." I'm getting an exception "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: '**There was an error deserializing the object of type UWPWeather.RootObject. The value '7.25' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.'
Value was either too large or too small for an Int32"**. I don't really understand where and what exactly should be changed in order for this to work.

Update: Got it working, changed some fields in RootObject class to double. I'm utterly confused why RootObject class that I got from parsing json file had incorrect field types but oh well, huge thanks to everyone.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `var` with `Int64`?

Comment: your RootObject is probably having a property of type Int32 while variable 'ms' contains value larger/incompatible with that . thus throws exception when mapping back to RootObject

Comment: Well, I guess but RootObject comes from json file, which comes from Open Weather map

Comment: @Adam Kingsley where?

Comment: @Agent_0f_things the `var` in front of `data`. It is possible your data just won't fit in an `Int32` but your program doesn't know that until runtime. So tell it beforehand by changing the line from `var data` . . . to `Int64 data` . . .

Comment: @AdamKingsley Int64 won't work for that either, the value it is failing on is `7.25`, it needs to be a type that can hold decimal based numbers.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I saw your answer. You are correct of course. I didn't know what number was going into the cast so I just made a guess.

Comment: It was right there in bold *The value '7.25' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'*

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I see that now. It wasn't there when the question was posted and my original comment.

Comment: @Agent_0f_things when you parsed the json it was a number with no decimal places so it did it's best guess and with it just saw a `1` (or whatever value it was in your example template) it assumed the number would always be a `int`.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain Lesson learned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it is telling you is in the `RootObject` class (or in the type for one of the fields if you have classes inside the class) you have a property or field that is of type `int` or `Int32`.

You are passing in `7.25` in the data you are deserializing, `7.25` can't be assigned to a `int` it can only be assigned to a `float`, `double` or `decimal`. You need to update your `RootObject` class (or one of the classes it holds inside of it) and fix the field that is incorrectly set up as an `int`.